For which topologies do self-homeomorphisms preserve the collection of open sets?
Inspired by Does a homeomorphism preserve the open sets?, I wanted to ask the corresponding question: while $X$ may have a topology $\mathcal T$ and a homeomorphism from $(X,\mathcal T)$ to $(X,\mathcal T')$ such that $\mathcal T\neq \mathcal T'$, under what conditions must $\mathcal T= \mathcal T'$? A simple example is the discrete topology; can this be generalized?

You must be using some idiosyncratic definition of "auto-homeomorphism" but I'm not sure what it is.  By an "auto-homeomorphism" of a topological space $(X,\mathcal T)$ do you just mean a permutation of the set $X$??

You don't mean "auto-homeomorphism", which would require the same topological space (set+topology) as both domain and co-domain. You mean honeomorphism between two topological spaces on the same underlying set.

In a comment to the linked question, Izaak van Dongen gave further examples, for instance the cofinite topology, cocountable topology etc.

In short, you are asking what are "permutation invariant topologies" (Izaak van Dongen's terminology is clearest here).

Just rephrasing:  "each bijective function from $X \rightarrow X$ is a homeomorphism from $(X,\mathcal T) \rightarrow (X,\mathcal T)$".

I'll expand on my comment from the other question. My claim is that every such
permutation-invariant topology is the co-$\kappa$ topology for some cardinal
$\kappa$. By this I mean: a set is closed if and only if it's equal to $X$ or it
has cardinality strictly less than $\kappa$. These spaces are clearly all
permutation-invariant. They include the discrete
space ($\kappa > |X|$), the indiscrete space ($\kappa = 1$),
the cofinite space ($\kappa = \aleph_0$), the cocountable space
($\kappa = \aleph_1$), etc.
So, suppose $(X, \tau)$ is permutation-invariant. I will take some cardinal
arithmetic for granted (of course, I'm assuming Choice), and I'll make use of
the fact that if we know $U \subseteq X$ is open/closed and we have $V \subseteq X$ with
$|U| = |V|$ and $|X \setminus U| = |X \setminus V|$, then $V$ must also be
open/closed. A special case of this is that if $|U| = |V| < |X|$, then $V$ must
be open/closed as we automatically obtain $|X \setminus U| = |X \setminus V|$.
We split into some cases:

First, suppose that $X$ is finite, and the topology is not the indiscrete
topology. Then some proper non-empty subset $\emptyset \subsetneq U \subsetneq
  X$ is open. It follows from this that some singleton set (and hence every
singleton set) is open, for example by considering all the permutations that
fix some point in $U$ and intersecting all the images of $U$ under
these permutations. So the space is discrete. So from now on, assume that $X$
is infinite.
Now, suppose that there is some nonempty open subset
$\emptyset \subsetneq U \subseteq X$
with $|U| < |X|$. Let $x \in U$. By cardinal arithmetic, we know that
$|U \setminus \{x\}| < |X \setminus U|$. So we can always find a subset $V'$ of
$X \setminus U$ with $|U \setminus \{x\}| = |V'|$. Letting $V = V' \cup \{x\}$, we have that
$|U| = |V|$ and $|X \setminus U| = |X \setminus V|$, so there is some
permutation taking $U$ to $V$. Hence $V$ is open, and hence $U \cap V = \{x\}$
is open, so the topology is discrete. So from now on, assume that every
nonempty open subset has the same cardinality as $X$.
Now let $A \subsetneq X$ be a proper closed subset. Suppose that $|A| = |X|$. We can also
assume that $|X \setminus A| = |X|$ by the previous. Hence any subset of
cardinality $|X|$ with complement also of cardinality $|X|$ is open. It
follows that $A$ is clopen and if $x \in A$, then $A \setminus \{x\}$ is also
clopen, and hence $\{x\}$ is open, so the topology was discrete again. So from
now on, assume that every proper closed subset has cardinality less than
$|X|$.
So let $A \subsetneq X$ be a proper closed subset, now assuming that
$|A| < |X|$. Let $B \subseteq X$ be a subset with $|B| \le |A|$. We'd like to
show that $B$ is also closed. Again, by cardinal arithmetic, we know that
there's a cardinal $\nu$ such that $\nu + |B| = |A|$ and
$2\nu < |X \setminus B|$ (take $\nu = |A|$ if $A$ is infinite, and
$\nu = |A| - |B|$ otherwise). So
there must be disjoint subsets $A_1', A_2' \subseteq X \setminus B$
with $|A_1'| = |A_2'| = \nu$. Then let $A_1 = A_1' \cup B$ and $A_2 = A_2' \cup B$.
We have $|A_1| = |A_2| = |A|$, so these subsets $A_1$ and $A_2$
must be closed and $A_1 \cap A_2 = B$, so it follows that $B$ is closed. This
completes the classification.

At the end, I have used the following fact:
Lemma. Suppose $(X, \tau)$ is a topological space and whenever
$A \subsetneq X$ is closed and $B \subseteq X$ has $|B| \le |A|$, it follows
that $B$ is closed. Then $\tau$ is a co-$\kappa$ topology for some $\kappa$.
(Proof. Take $\kappa$ = $\sup\{|A|^+ : \text{$A \subsetneq X$ is closed}\}$)
